# Facebook Messenger Quick Reply Button in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, facebook-messenger, amazon-lex

I am currently trying to add quick reply buttons to my messenger chatbot that I have developed using Amazon Lex and Python in Amazon Lambda. I found this on Facebook's for developer site:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "message":{
    "text": "Here's a quick reply!",
    "quick_replies":[
      {
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Search",
        "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/red.png"
      },
      {
        "content_type":"location"
      },
      {
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Something Else",
        "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>"
      }
    ]
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

I have tried searching for solutions but they require the fbmessenger library. I was hoping to use urllib library instead of open source libraries. Is there a solution to this?

[Quick Reply Button in Messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjWZv.png)

```
def helpMe(intent_request):

session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}

return close(
    session_attributes,
    'Fulfilled',
    {
        'contentType': 'PlainText',
        'content': 'It seems like you need help, let me save you from your misery.\n\n' 
         + '- If you want to find '
         + 'out what insurance plan is suitable for your dear self, try asking me "Which integrated Shield Plan is right for me?".\n\n '
         + '- If you want me to explain about your current plan, you could try asking me ' 
         + '"Explain my current plan".\n\n '
         + '- If you wanna listen to my extremely hilarious puns, just type in "joke" and you will not regret it hehe. '
    },
    'responseCard': {
    'version': '0',
    'contentType': 'application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic',
    'genericAttachments': [
        {
        'title': 'Help',
        'subTitle': 'Select button of choice',
        'imageUrl': '',
        "buttons":[ 
             {
                "text":"recommend plan",
                "value":"Which integrated Shield Plan is right for me"
             },
             {
                "text":"current plan",
                "value":"Explain my current plan"
             },
             {
                "text":"tell me a joke",
                "value":"joke"
             }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a roughly how you can get and send.

Get Message:

```
data = request.get_json()

if data["object"] == "page":

    for entry in data["entry"]:
        for messaging_event in entry["messaging"]:

            if messaging_event.get("message"):

                sender_id = messaging_event["sender"]["id"]
                recipient_id = messaging_event["recipient"]["id"]
                message_text = messaging_event["message"]["text"]

                send_message(sender_id, "roger that!")

            if messaging_event.get("delivery"):
                pass

            if messaging_event.get("optin"):
                pass

            if messaging_event.get("postback"):
                pass

return "ok", 200
```

Send Message:

You can Just Include quick reply button code in

> "message"

```
def send_message(recipient_id, message_text):
    params = {
           "access_token": os.environ["PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
    }

    headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    data = json.dumps({
               "recipient": {
                      "id": recipient_id
               },
               "message": {
                  "text": message_text
                  "quick_replies":[{
                            "content_type":"text",
                            "title":"Search",
                            "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
                            "image_url":"http://example.com/img/red.png"
                            },
                            {
                             "content_type":"location"
                            },
                            {
                             "content_type":"text",
                             "title":"Something Else",
                             "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>"
                             }
                   ]
               }
    })
    r = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages", params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
```

In fact you can customize what you want based on curl example shown there.

Comment: Hi Salehin, thanks for replying. I have a question, where should I use this function in my codes to retrieve the slot reply? Is it like this?
**Current:**
'def insurance_bot(intent_request):
nationality = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['nation'])'

**Now:**
'def insurance_bot(intent_request):
        nationality = r'

Comment: you can check my simple chatbot how to get the intent value: https://github.com/salehinRafi/chatbot
But I use 3rd party library. But I believe its nothing major different. I prefer separate file for nice readable.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get recipient_id?

Comment: Salehin, instead of using the request library, can we use the urllib library from python?

Comment: @CJSee of course, u can. U can refer to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/q/47384859/4216992) how I use urllib and you can manipulate your code. Ignore unanswered question. I already found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with Lex and Lambda I think you want to send the response buttons to the user where he can proceed with the conversation.

Here is the way to do that in Lambda function:

```
'responseCard': {
    'version': '0',
    'contentType': 'application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic',
    'genericAttachments': [
        {
        'title': 'title1',
        "buttons":[ 
             {
                "text":"button_1",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_2",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_3",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can have these buttons in the Close message and ElicitSlot message as well, additionally you can have images along with the buttons as well.

Below is the code for having buttons and images in the Close message.

```
'dialogAction': {
    'type': 'Close',
    'fulfillmentState': 'Fulfilled',
    'message': {
        'contentType': 'PlainText',
        'content': message
    },
    'responseCard': {
    'version': '0',
    'contentType': 'application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic',
    'genericAttachments': [
        {
        'title': 'title1',
        'subTitle': 'subtitle1',
        'attachmentLinkUrl': 'link_that_will_open_on_click',
        'imageUrl': 'link_of_image_to_display',
        "buttons":[ 
             {
                "text":"button_1",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_2",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_3",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             }
            ]
        },
        {
        'title': 'title2',
        'subTitle': 'subtitle2',
        'attachmentLinkUrl': 'link_that_will_open_on_click',
        'imageUrl': 'link_of_image_to_display',
        "buttons":[ 
             {
                "text":"button_1",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_2",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_3",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             }
            ]
        },
        {
        'title': 'title3',
        'subTitle': 'subtitle3',
        'attachmentLinkUrl': 'link_that_will_open_on_click',
        'imageUrl': 'link_of_image_to_display',
        "buttons":[ 
             {
                "text":"button_1",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_2",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_3",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

NOTE: You can have **maximum of 3 buttons** in a single carousel although you can add upto 10 carousel in single message. If you have more than 3 buttons, you won't get error but only first 3 will be shown.

**You need to check `messaging_postbacks` events in the `Webhooks` in messenger settings in the Facebook app to make buttons of carousel work.**

You will get reply in messenger like this:
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi sid8491, thanks for replying. Actually, I am referring to the quick reply button in messenger. I have added an example "Quick Reply Button in Messenger" in my question. Do you have a solution to that?

Comment: this will add quick reply button in the messenger only, i have update the answer with a picture also, please check. these buttons can be used to show information, get slot information, and other things.

Comment: I have changed the image to show a better example. Can the response card method work too?

Comment: @CJSee yes it will work. but the way buttons are shown on FB is different if we use Lex. try the first code which I have posted in the `ElicitSlot` code to get size or color

Comment: Hi sid8491, I have added the codes in the my question. Is this what you meant?

Comment: yep. does this complete your requirement?

Comment: But I am getting a syntax error in the line **'responseCard': {** I cannot seem to find my error

Comment: post your `close()` method as well